# line 45: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: syntax, line, ksh

When I try running the script, I am gettin the error line 45: syntax error: unexpected end of file. I am relatively new to scripting. Please help me resolve it.

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -xv

export HOME=/home/mine


. $HOME/.env.ksh



BIS_SPOOL=/tmp/bis_table_mine.spl
BIS_REPORT_MINE=/tmp/bis_table_report_mine.txt

touch $BIS_SPOOL
rm $BIS_SPOOL
touch $BIS_SPOOL

       exec 5< $BIS_REPORT_MINE

         while read -u5 REC_MINE
         do
          TBLENAME=`echo "$REC_MINE" | awk '{print $3}' |  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

           sqlplus -s ${USER_ID}/${USER_PASS}@${ORACLE_SID} <<- EOF
           set feedback off
       set hea ON
       set pagesize 9999
       set linesize 9999
       set trimspool ON
       set termout off
       spool $BIS_SPOOL append
       Column C1 Heading          'Job Name'                Format  a30 
           Column C2 Heading          'Table Name'              Format  a30
           SELECT job_name   C1,
                 table_name C2,
           FROM table_usage
           WHERE table_name like 'TBLENAME%'
          /
          exit;
          EOF
done

   exec 5<& -
```

Comment: The end `EOF` should not be indented. In general I'd recommend properly indenting *all* the code and using http://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Can you post specifically what error you are getting back?

Comment: Hi Mike, this is the exact error I am getting
line 45: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

The `<<- EOS` is interpreted literally. Make it

```
sqlplus -s ${USER_ID}/${USER_PASS}@${ORACLE_SID} <<-EOF
```

without the space char.

Also make sure there is no space char before or after your closing `EOS` , but leading tab chars are allowed.

IHTH